# How to return when function is called from another function? iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I am working on my first iPhone game and am wondering how to return a value from a function when this first function calls a second function? The functions returns `bool`s.

Here is some sample code:

```
// This is sample calls to inrect functions:
[menuButton inrect:point] // Calls the first function which calls second function
[menuButton inrect:point:0.5] // No problem because calls the second function directly
```

Here are functions:

```
- (BOOL) inrect:(CGPoint)_point{
    [self inrect:_point:0]; //call second function with offset of 0
    return 0; //How do I return the value of the above call?
}

- (BOOL) inrect:(CGPoint)_point:(float)offset{
    if (_point > 0 && offset > 1) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (_point < 0 && offset < 1) {
        return YES;
    }   
    return NO;
}
```

There is no problem when I call the second function directly, but when calling the first function, which in turns calls the second function, how do I properly return the value of the second function back to the first function so it can return it to where it was called from.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm getting you. Just return it:

```
return [self inrect:_point:0];
```

Comment: Yes this is what I needed! Very obvious now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to understand your problem, but maybe you want to do this:

```
- (BOOL) inrect:(CGPoint)_point
    {
        BOOL aBool = [self inrect:_point:0]; //put the return in a BOOL and do what you want with it
        NSLog(@"Not expecting to this, but I do!");
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT

```
- (BOOL) inrect:(CGPoint)_point
    {
        return [self inrect:_point:0];
    }
```

Comment: I guess you mean `return aBool;`